# Having a big debate need a third opinion helllp

Tags: poker-history, soft-question

So, player one has Q 5 in his hand, and player two has 2 4 . 
Now on the table there are 7 7 2 8 8 . 
Somebody please tell me, who is the winner player 1 or player 2?
I say it is player one since it the biggest 2 pairs are 7s and 8s. But all my frineds say that i am wrong but i cant manage to understand why. Sorry for the silly question.

Answer (score 1):

Player 1 is the winner. He had 7 7 8 8 Q. Player 2 has 7 7 8 8 4. Two pair, lower kicker.

Comment: Minor correction: Player 2 has 7 7 8 8 4. Also it is more common to write 8 8 7 7 instead of 7 7 8 8.

Comment: True. I modified my answer.